# jquery text() method with blank spaces

Tags: jquery

With `$('h1').text(),` I can have all the text of the h1 that exist in the body (there's only one h1 element). But in my case, the text has a lot of blank spaces in it like:

```
<h1>            hello text          </h1>
```

How could I retrieve only the text but not the blank spaces in the beginning and in the end of the text? I want only "hello text".

For testing:

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/42du0j5r/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [$.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):-

```
$.trim($('h1').text());
```

Or you can use that in below way too:-

```
$('h1').text().trim();
```

Example:-https://jsfiddle.net/dryt8r2m/

Comment: or `$('h1').text().trim()`

Comment: Thanks! I have to wait some minutes to select the answer as the correct one.

Comment: @pmirnd  glad to help you :):)